# SQL select statement from 2 tables

Tags: sql, select

I have a small sql question.

I have 2 tables

Members and Managers

Members has: memberID, Name, Address
Managers has: memberID, EditRights, DeleteRights

EditRights and DeleteRights are of type bit.

Mangers have a relationship with Members, because they are members themselves.

I want to select all members id's, name and adress and for the members that are managers show if they have editrights and/or deleterights.

SO:

Exmaple data

Members:

```
ID, Name, Address
1, tom, 2 flat
2, dan, 3 flat
3, ben, 4 flat
4, bob, 6 flat
5, sam, 9 flat
```

Managers:

```
ID, Editrights, deleterights 
2, 0, 1
4, 1, 1
5, 0, 0
```

I would like to display a select like this:

```
1, tom, 2 flat, no rights
2, dan, 3 flat, Delete
3, ben, 4 flat, no rights
4, bob, 6 flat, Edit&Delete
5, sam, 9 flat, no rights
```

Any help would be great

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532694/sql-select-rows-from-two-different-tables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231126/mysql-get-information-from-multiple-tables-in-one-query, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363555/help-building-a-sql-query-from-multiple-tables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693327/sql-how-to-join-multiple-tables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485210/mysql-need-help-constructing-query-join-multiple-tables-into-single-row

Comment: If you've received a satisfactory answer, you should mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM members LEFT OUTER JOIN managers ON member.id = manager.id
```

I wouldn't recommend concatenating the rights columns into strings like "no rights" - that's something better left to the presentation side of your application.  Return as much data as possible in its native form so you can more easily work with it later.

Comment: Updated to take advantage of the insight by @Andrew: you need a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get all members, regardless of whether they have an entry in the manager table.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a left join

Answer (score 1):

I think this is closer to what you're asking for. The OUTER term is what gets you members that aren't in the Managers table. The CASE.. + stuff might need some tweaking to work with whatever DB you're using, but you get the idea - @ABach is correct about handling this in your presentation code if you can.

```
SELECT m.ID, m.Name, m.Address,
CASE WHERE g.EditRights IS NULL AND g.deleterights IS NULL THEN 'no rights'
ELSE
  CASE WHERE g.Editrights = 1 THEN 'Edit' END
  + CASE WHERE g.Editrights = 1 AND g.deleterights = 1 THEN '&' END
  + CASE WHERE g.deleterights = 1 THEN 'Delete' END
END AS rights
FROM Members AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN Managers AS g ON g.ID = m.ID
```